# add generateAppStoreInformation in exportOptions.plist file in Fastfile

Tags: xcode, plist, fastlane, fastlane-gym, fastfile

I am trying to add generateAppStoreInformation as true in exportOptions.plist. but it is showing this error :
What is best way and command to add `generateAppStoreInformation` in fastlane file.

What is the exact syntax to add generateAppStoreInformation as true in Fastfile

```
Could not find action, lane or variable 'export_options'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions



gym(
      scheme: "XXX",
      configuration: options[:config],
      output_directory: output_directory,
      codesigning_identity: "XXXXXX"
    )

    export_options(
         generateAppStoreInformation: true
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter `generateAppStoreInformation` in fastlane.

Documentation: http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_ios_app/#parameters

What was exactly your intention?